# How do I change the CSS property "display" in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, block

How do I change the CSS property `display`, in JavaScript, from `display:none` to `display:normal` for these divs?

```css
#hide_0 { display:none }
#hide_1 { display:none }
#hide_2 { display:none }
#hide_3 { display:none }
#hide_4 { display:none }
#hide_5 { display:none }
```

Only one at a time.  I need to display one and hide the rest.

What I used:

```
var persistent_element='hide_1';

function link_update(link_display)
  {
  var local_element;
  local_element=document.getElementById(persistent_element);  
  local_element.style.display='none';
  local_element=document.getElementById(link_display);
  local_element.style.display='block';
  persistent_element=link_display;
  }
```

How I connected it : m4 is a minified - connects onclick to these methods

```
m4('l1',function {return link_update(hide_1);}); 
m4('l2',function {return link_update(hide_2);});
m4('l3',function {return link_update(hide_3);});
m4('l4',function {return link_update(hide_4);});
m4('l5',function {return link_update(hide_5);});
m4('l6',function {return link_update(hide_6);});
```

Comment: Note that [“`normal`” is not a valid value for the CSS `display` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop).

Comment: Points for everyone who didn't say "JUST USE JQUERY!!!111"

Comment: @MikeRobinson - I agree, it's good to answer JS questions without jQuery (when the OP doesn't mention jQuery), but it really would make this so much easier!

Comment: you write `connects onclick` ,How you connect without showing in your html ! You had set display none all in your css is can't handle onclick [without display]

Answer (score 10):

To use javascript to change the style, you can do it like this:

```
// hide an element
document.getElementById("hide_0").style.display = "none";

// show a block element
document.getElementById("hide_1").style.display = "block";

// to go back to the default or CSS specified value
document.getElementById("hide_2").style.display = "";
```

So, if you wanted to hide all and show one, you could do that with this function:

```
function showOneHideOthers(base, len, numToShow) {
    // objects must have ids like base_0, base_1, etc...
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (i != numToShow) {
            document.getElementById(base+i).style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById(base+numToShow).style.display = "block";
}

showOneHideOther("hide_", 6, 2);
```

---

P.S.  `normal` is not a valid value for the display property.  The typical values are `block`, `none` and `inline` and there are others like `inline-block`, `table`, etc....

Comment: You can either hide all the other ones (it doesn't hurt to hide something that is already hidden) or you can keep a variable that remembers the currently visible one so you can just hide that one.  I added a function to do that to my answer.

Comment: I added a code example to my answer that doesn't need that variable.  You just call a function with the base name, the number of total items and the one you want to be shown.

Comment: easier to keep one variable...please look at my edit...will this work?

Comment: Your code is the general idea, but it looks like you use `link_hide` in one place and `persistent_element` in another and you have to assign `persistent_element` to the value that you just made visible.

Comment: It looks like what you have should work.  My method didn't require any global variables or any state (that's why I wrote it that way).  In a small project, appropriately and uniquely named globals are no big deal.  In a large project, globals should be namespaced to avoid top level naming collisions.

Comment: The global variable only exists during the lifetime of the page (it is in the temporarily loaded copy of the page only).  It will not persist for any other page or even when they come back to this page.

Comment: Thanks for the input..incorporated it into the quesiton/answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not particularly clear, but the essence of what you want to do is simple. You can get a reference to a DOM element which has an `id` using `getElementById`, and you can change the `display` property:

```
document.getElementById("hide_0").style.display = "none"; //or "block"
```

However, you have several element that you want to hide/show (I'm not sure when you want to do so), so it may be easier to use a different method of selecting the elements (such as `getElementsByTagName`, or `getElementsByClassName`, but it depends on your HTML and what you're actually trying to do).

Comment: Excellent...how do I hide the previously visible div...is there a way to have javascript remember the previously visible div via a staic variable of sorts?...thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set a css property on an element using the style method.

```
div.style.display = '';
```

Comment: This won't work as the styles are being set via CSS.  To override them you need to actually specify a value to override them with.

Comment: no, it's not. Valid values are listed at http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#the-lsquo.  What you have would work if `display` were set from an inline style attribute, but not from a stylesheet.